# Starved Dispatcher's message pump?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading

I'm developing a C#/WPF Application running lengthy data Uploads to a server.
For this, I launch a dialog window, which launches a backgroundWorker thread.
The worker thread processes the file uploads.
The UI  Updates are done with Application.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() calls.
The file uploads use HttpClient, calling Task.Run() for the async part.

After a long time ( 1h1/2, 2hrs..) , I have an exception on the GC Finalizer thread:

> WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.OnRequestProcessingFailure(string methodName)   Unknown
> WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.RequestForegroundProcessing()   Unknown
> WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CriticalRequestProcessing(bool force)   Unknown
> WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeAsyncImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation operation, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)   Unknown
> WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyBeginInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs)   Unknown
> WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.Dispose(bool disposing, bool isHwndBeingDestroyed) Unknown
> WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.~HwndWrapper() Unknown

The exception is an InvalidOperationException, HResult 0x80131509, with the following message:

`The Dispatcher is unable to request processing.  This is often because the application has starved the Dispatcher's message pump.`

I don't understand what this exception means ? I can't find any explanation
on the NET..

I had an issue where the dispatcher could not process the messages from the worker thread because there were too many, and added a a Hook on the Dispatcher to watch the queue length. When the exception is triggered, the queue length is small ( < 10).

The Main Thread seems to be running the dispatcher's message pump:

> WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.GetMessageW(ref System.Windows.Interop.MSG msg, System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef hWnd, int uMsgFilterMin, int uMsgFilterMax)  Unknown
> WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.GetMessage(ref System.Windows.Interop.MSG msg, System.IntPtr hwnd, int minMessage, int maxMessage)  Unknown
> WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame)   Unknown
> PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(object booleanBox)   Unknown
> PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Window.ShowDialog()    Unknown

Any hint on how to fix this will be greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: In BeginInvoke you update Wpf controls directly (i.e. label1.Text = "...") or through binding?

Comment: In BeginInvoke, I update Wpf controls directly (ProgressBar;Value=.., Message.Text=..)

Comment: I've read some threads about Dispatcher and people say it's quite a misterious thing and works not like Invoke in winforms. As a recommendation, I've seen advice to switch to use binding instead of raw control change. Try it, for example, only for ProgressBar

Comment: @Clemens I would love to provide a mimimal reproducible example, but please understand the process is complex & the bug difficult & long to reproduce. Providing this miminal example will take days at least. I hope for a hint, at least an explanation on that message I just haven't seen anywhere else on SO..

Comment: I've seen this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/980de216-c38c-4c6a-a3f6-abaf01a0617f/wpf-message-pump-not-responding?forum=wpf